# Java - Using JSch but getting an error when trying to move a file on FTP - %RNFR-bad%

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I'm trying to use the rename functionality and keep getting this error.
Stacktrace:

```
3: %RNFR-bad%
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.rename(ChannelSftp.java:1950)
    ...
```

Here's the method I'm using to move the file

```
private void moveFile(String sourcePath, String destinationPath) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Move: " + sourcePath + " to: " + destinationPath);
        sftp.rename(sourcePath, destinationPath);  //sftp = ChannelSftp
    } catch (SftpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here's the output for my println:

```
Move: /SND/OUTBOUND/TestOutboundFile1.txt to: /SND/OUTBOUND/PROCESSING/TestOutboundFile1.txt
```

I've tried some other options posted around on here (get then put, multiple connections, etc) but keep getting the same error or it just sits and hangs (this was happening with the get then put method).  Everything I've seen on the web says this should be as easy as my method but I just can't seem to get it to work.  Can't find anything with the "RNFR-bad" error that is useful either.

The destination directory already exists and it's empty.  What am I missing?  Any help much appreciated.

**EDIT**: This ended up being a permissions issue and the code posted above worked perfectly fine after the admin granted my account the correct permissions.  I was able to create and delete both files and directories but was unable to rename files until account privs were modified.

Comment: Can you move the file using any commandline/GUI SFTP client?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl no, I get the same %RNFR-bad% error.

Comment: OK, then you do not have a programming question. Please ask at [su] or [sf]. Or even better the support of your SFTP server vendor/provider.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks buddy.  Since I could do everything except move the file (rename), I assumed I was doing something wrong.  Didn't even cross my mind to try outside of my code.  I've run across your comments/answers on other questions here on this topic, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
3: %RNFR-bad%
```

[SFTP error code 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13#section-9.1) means "permission denied". This implies that you're getting an error because you don't have permission on the remote system to perform the file move operation that you're trying to do.

"%RNFR-bad%" doesn't seem to be meaningful. My guess is that the remote SFTP server is using [localized messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) and it doesn't have a proper message for this case, or it's malfunctioning in some other way.

Comment: I have read/write/delete access and can create and remove directories and files.  Someone else controls the server, is there something specific I need to ask for that would allow this?